# MVVM ViewModel Passing Parameters to another ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM-Light and I have a DataGrid working that has Salesmen listed.  The user can double-click to open a child window that will have their sales listed on a grid and the user will be able fill in some textboxes under that grid to add a new sale.

I am trying to use two seperate ViewModels to make this happen - one for the salesmen list and one for the sales list.  The part that is messing me up is Salesman grid passes the Selected Salesman to the Sales Items code-behind, but the place where I actually need it is in the ViewModel.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're "passing" it to the Items code-behind and you need it in the ViewModel, why are you just not giving it to the ViewModel?

Comment: Peter, right, that's where I need it to go, the ViewModel.  How do I give it to the ViewModel?

Comment: Without seeing your ViewModel, I couldn't begin to tell you how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a ViewModel assign a the salesman to a property of the viewmodel. Then give your View the Viewmodel instead.

Or if you are using dependency injection, you could create your ViewModel, have an interface to the view get injected into the constructor, set ViewModel.SalesPerson = person, and call ViewModel.Present() which calls IView.ShowDialog().